# Creating determinant function for optimization in SciPy

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to learn how to use scipy.optimize. As a warm up example,
I am trying to minimize the determinant of 2 by 2 matrices with entries
bounded in absolute value by .5. I define a function det(x) which takes
in four numbers, puts them in a square numpy array, and returns the determinant. It seems to work. Then when I try to minimize that function,
I get the error "Objective function must return a scalar". What's going on?

Here is my code:

```
n=2

import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def det(x):
    A=np.zeros((n,n))
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            A[i,j]=x[2*i+j]
    return np.linalg.det(A)

x0=[.01,-.01,.02,-.1] 

b=(-0.5,0.5)
bnds=[b,b,b,b]


sol=minimize(det(x),x0,method='SLSQP',bounds=bnds)

print(sol)
```

Comment: `det` is a python function, `det(x)` is a call to the `det` function passing `x` as argument, so `det(x)` is understood as the returned value. Try with `minimize(det, x0, ...)`

Comment: Sorry xdze2 we were posting at the same time...

Comment: @jtlz2 no problem, it is actually better to post an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the following rather?

```
sol=minimize(det,x0,method='SLSQP',bounds=bnds)
```

->

```
     fun: -0.49999999712754745
     jac: array([-0.5, -0.5, -0.5,  0.5])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
    nfev: 42
     nit: 7
    njev: 7
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([ 0.5,  0.5,  0.5, -0.5])
```